# Normalize images for Sentinel

Tags: qgis, python, rasterio

I want to join different bands from Sentinel-2 to create index images (such NDVI, EVI...). I know how to open, mix and save the stack using rasterio. However, I have a technical question related with this composition and I want to know how the community does these stacking since I'm new in the field.

When you do this stacking, do you do something on the images feeding the composition? For example, let's take EVI. From Sentinel-2 you need to read bands 4, 2, 8A for RGB channels. But, after opening them, do you normalize these bands? In case you normalize, do you normalize each channel individually, or do you take the largest and lowest value among the three channels? Which algorithm to normalize do you apply, if any?

Answer (score 2):

There are several [product levels](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/processing-levels) for Sentinel-2. For vegetation indices, I would recommend using bottom-of-atmosphere products (level 2A). No need for normalization as far as I know.

Please note that raflectance values for Sentinel 2 are on a 0-10000 scale instead of 0-1. You need to consider the conversion in the EVI formula.

Comment: Actually my idea was to use 2A, or in some strange scenario 1C. Therefore I need to normalize always 10000 <-> 255, 0<->0 with linear transformation in between? or should images be 16-bit and do 10000 <-> 65536?

Comment: Vegetation indices are calculated based on reflectance values. These range from 0 (all light is absorbed) to 1 (all light is reflected). Float values take up more storage space than integers. I believe this is why ESA chose a 0-10000 range. To get the reflectance value, you just need to divide your Sentinel2 DN by 10000.